# Channel Videos not saving new videos (EE2 site upgraded to EE4)

Tags: channel, cache, channel-videos

**Background:**

EE2 site with channel videos among other plugins. Following a successful upgrade to EE4.3.1 the site is functioning correctly, and old videos are working.

The issues begin when trying to add new videos, they can be found successfully, or added directly from a url, but upon saving, they disappear. The video also doesn't seem to find a date, it just returns invalid date.

This issue is similar to this question: [Channel Videos - Removing Video When Saving](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/39420/channel-videos-removing-video-when-saving)

The plugin code that we have now is downloaded from the Dev Demon site, before the migration to EE Harbor.

I've tested with the EE Harbor code also, but it presents more issues matching this question: [Channel Videos Error](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/38080/channel-videos-error)

**Testing & Debugging:**

Following some of the similar threads, I've double checked and the cache folder is accessible. I've dumped the $data payloads that are passed into the save() and post_save() functions in the ft.channel_videos.php file. The issue seems to lie here. Data is blank within post_save() as it's attempting to retrieve the data from the ee cache. I don't believe it's successfully writing to the ee cache folder even though it's writable and other plugins aren't having similar issues.

**Also to Note:**

When installing the plugin on a site with PHP 7+ . (Required by EE4), there are numerous PHP issues, to do with direct assignment of the instance, requiring a change from:

```
// Creat EE Instance
$this->EE =& get_instance();
```

to:

```
// Creat EE Instance
$this->EE = get_instance();
```

**Request:**

What could be happening when saving? Support will currently be slow while EE Harbor acquire Dev Demon, and I have a ticket in but urgently need to fix a live site. I will add new info as I come across it while debugging.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out, it's not compatible with EE4 based on the way EE4 handles fields in the DB. It's being handled by EE Harbor but is a low priority task as it's a free plugin.